# How can I make a table in a "code block" on my Squarespace site responsive?

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, html-table, responsive

I have [a website](http://www.familyhistoryconferencenwa.org) built on the [Squarespace](http://squarespace.com) platform. Using a Squarespace "code block" I inserted the HTML for a table on [this /test page](http://www.familyhistoryconferencenwa.org/test). The table is not responsive.

I would like the table to display on mobile devices as if it were in an `<iframe>` with horizontal scrolling. On screen resizing down, on whatever device, I need the columns not to narrow beyond a certain point, say min-width: 150px.

I've searched this site and read many of the nearly 7,000 results on the terms "responsive table" but found nothing that seems to be on point. I've searched CSS Tricks but found nothing, which isn't surprising since I think it can't be done with CSS only. I searched the Squarespace Answers Forum of course but found no help.

I created [this Pen](http://codepen.io/alxfyv/pen/mPGbmW?editors=1100) on CodePen which behaves like I want. The same HTML in a Squarespace code block does not.

I'm thinking that this will require some JavaScript of which I have no knowledge. So I'm wondering whether anyone here can help.

Thank you for your interest in my question. Any help will of course be much appreciated.

Comment: wrap the table in a `<div>` with a fixed width and `overflow-x: auto` style

Comment: Thanks very much. I found essentially that answer at [Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/html_tables) when I told it to make the table responsive. I should have thought to do that before asking the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting the question I went to [Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/html_tables), the HTML Tables tab, and found that it had an option, under the Extra Options drop down selector, to make the table responsive. That option generated an `@media` query which did the trick.

The overarching markup I used is:

```
<div class="schedule-wrapper">
  <table class="schedule">
  ...
  </table>
</div>
```

The CSS I used is:

```
@media only screen
  and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .schedule-wrapper {
      -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
      overflow-x: auto;
      margin: auto 0;
    }
    .schedule {
      width: auto;
    }
}
```

I modified the pen [Table Play](http://codepen.io/alxfyv/pen/mPGbmW?editors=1100) to reflect this and will leave it up in case anyone wants it for reference.

It seems to have turned out to be doable with CSS only. How cool.